# What does this command do? <a href="mailto:?">

Tags: html, command

Could somebody help me? The question is up above.

Answer (score 0):

The `mailto` opens the default mail client as explained [here](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/mailto.htm). You can added additional paramaters,

```
<a href="mailto:test@email.com?cc=cc@email.com&bcc=bbc@email.com>
```

Send mail with cc and bcc

Note that the first parameter is delimited by `?` while the rest are delimited by `&`. You can also have subject and body parameters.